# ImageView shows the same image even after changing the bytes

Tags: android, imageview

I am developing an Android app in which I send images from PC to my Android phone via Bluetooth, and display them in an ImageView one at a time. When the user presses a "next" button, the next image should be displayed.

The first image that I send is displayed properly; however, when the user presses the "next" button, the same first image is displayed again even though the bytes of the second image are being successfully decoded using `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()`.

Here is the code:

```
public void displayImage()
{
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { 
            setContentView(R.layout.screen); 
            imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
            if (scrn[img_no] == null) 
                Log.d("Screen","Screen in null"); 
            else { 
                imv.setImageBitmap(scrn[img_no]); 
                imv.postInvalidate(); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

`scrn[]` is a `Bitmap` array which I am initializing above in the code and `img_no` is a counter which increments by 1 on pressing next and decrements by 1 on pressing previous

Comment: Do you get any console output?

Comment: I am displaying the bytes just before the setImageBitmap method. I have removed it in the code above just to avoid unnecessary code and reduce the size. The Log is showing me the bytes of the new image correctly, but imageview shows the first image only

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally..
Just reinitialized the DataInputStream from which i was reading the image bytes. It seems that the first image bytes were being overwritten again and again and so the same image was displayed.. Strange but true.. Hope it helps some of you